# What does it mean apply-templates select='*'?

Tags: xml, xslt, cruisecontrol.net

Forgive me I just learned the `XSL`, And I have trouble to understand the apply-templates well. In my understanding. `apply-templates` will find the nodes match the `select`. and search in the current xsl document if there is a `template` defined for specified select nodes. then apply the style to these nodes.

For Example:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<h2>My CD Collection</h2> 
<xsl:apply-templates/> 
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
<p>
<xsl:apply-templates select="title"/> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
</p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
Title: <span style="color:#ff0000">
<xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
<br />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
Artist: <span style="color:#00ff00">
<xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
<br />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- The first apply-templates in the `<xsl:template match="/">`, It means all the nodes under the root `catalog` will apply the specified template. since there is a template already defined for these nodes. so it will apply the template to these nodes `cd`. And So does the other apply-templates. They works with the same rule.

But when I see the xsl like below. actually there are from cruisecontrol.net `MsTestReport2010.xsl`

```
<xsl:variable name="runinfos"
                  select="*[local-name()='ResultSummary']/*[local-name()='RunInfos']/*[local-name()='RunInfo']" />
    <xsl:if test="count($runinfos) > 0">
      <h3>Errors and Warnings</h3>
      <table width="100%"
             border="1"
             cellSpacing="0"
             style="font-size:small;">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$runinfos" />
      </table>
    </xsl:if>
```

in my understanding the `xsl:apply-templates select="$runinfos"` will search the xsl document find the template defined for it. which is the below.

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='RunInfo']">
    <tr>
      <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

But What make me confused is what does it mean `select="*"`. Because I seach in the xsl document .found there is not such `*` template defined for it ..

And I also wonder a question : What if there is no template match the selected nodes in the `xsl:apply-templates` ?

And How I can test and debug a xsl in some tools . Please share it with me if you have some good ones.Thanks.

Here is the xml

```
<cruisecontrol project="KMIMProject">
    <build date="2015-10-09 19:01:32" buildtime="00:00:35" error="true" buildcondition="ForceBuild">
        <TestRun id="1bd2dff0-7418-4a1e-8ffd-189b27d1b118" name="Administrator@JOE-WANGPC 2015-10-09 19:01:26" runUser="JOE-WANGPC\Administrator" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
            <TestSettings name="Default Test Settings" id="6e1f3ea2-9cf0-4beb-8305-1a4b5db1fa55">
                <Deployment userDeploymentRoot="E:\study\cc.net\Test\KMIH\WorkingFolder" useDefaultDeploymentRoot="false" runDeploymentRoot="Administrator_JOE-WANGPC 2015-10-09 19_01_26"/>
                <Execution>
                    <TestTypeSpecific/>
                    <AgentRule name="Execution Agents">
      </AgentRule>
                </Execution>
                <Properties/>
            </TestSettings>
            <Times creation="2015-10-09T19:01:26.3934012+08:00" queuing="2015-10-09T19:01:26.6424154+08:00" start="2015-10-09T19:01:26.7014188+08:00" finish="2015-10-09T19:01:27.1244430+08:00"/>
            <ResultSummary outcome="Failed">
                <Counters total="106" executed="59" error="0" failed="59" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="47" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" passed="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0"/>
                <RunInfos>
                    <RunInfo computerName="JOE-WANGPC" outcome="Warning" timestamp="2015-10-09T19:01:26.4934069+08:00">
                        <Text>Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'KMIH.Persistence' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'E:\study\cc.net\Test\KMIH\SourceCheckOutFolder\kmih.unittests\obj\release\kmih.unittests.dll' was not found.</Text>
                    </RunInfo>
                    <RunInfo computerName="JOE-WANGPC" outcome="Warning" timestamp="2015-10-09T19:01:26.4934069+08:00">
                        <Text>Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'KMIH.WebUI' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'E:\study\cc.net\Test\KMIH\SourceCheckOutFolder\kmih.unittests\obj\release\kmih.unittests.dll' was not found.</Text>
                    </RunInfo>
                </RunInfos>
            </ResultSummary>
        </TestRun>
    </build>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Comment: "Forgive me I just learned the XSL". As a matter of interest, how did you go about learning it? Because whatever you did, you somehow missed out the central most important concept in the language. Personally, if I have to learn a language, the first thing I do is to buy a book and read it cover-to-cover. Some people consider that old-fashioned, or they are too impatient and want results instantly. But I have trouble using a language until I understand its core concepts, and the fact that you ask this question suggests that you are the same.

Comment: Yes, you are totally Right. Could you please kindly recommend some good books to me. Currently I just learn it in the W3cSchool. And try to figure out this kind of problem I encountered. I really feel like a child in front of you. Sorry for that . Please forgive me.

Comment: My own book "XSLT 2.0 Programmer's reference" is a very comprehensive reference book that also includes analysis of concepts. If you prefer a gentler and more tutorial approach that's geared to presenting once concept at a time, Jeni Tennison's Introduction to XSLT 2.0 might suit you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means "select all element children and apply the templates that match them." So if there is, for example, a child tag `meh` and a template for any element matching `meh` (or a more general match), it would apply that template for that child element. The `apply-templates` does not choose the template, it only tells the engine that templates should be applied to the selection (in the `select` attribute) and the engine should find the appropriate templates for them.

If there is no template matching an element, XSLT has built-in rules that basically say "apply templates to all child elements also, and if there are text nodes, copy them to output". So in this case since the elements inside RunInfo have no matching template, XSLT will just copy the text inside it to the output.

Comment: I mean which appropriate templates it will apply to `*` ? Thanks.

Comment: oh .. I got it  what you mean ..  But what if there is no templates that match some of them ? how to display this kind of children nodes ? Just raw text ? thanks.

Comment: @Joe.Wang Added some info about default templates

Comment: Very good .. It works as what I did in my experiments. Please help to review it . Thanks you help.

Answer (score 2):

From the [XPath Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

> `*` selects all element children of the context node