# XSLT: <apply-templates select="...">

Tags: xslt, apply-templates

I have a question regarding `<xsl:apply-templates>`.

Lets assume I have an XML like this (see http://www.tei-c.org/release/doc/tei-p5-doc/en/html/ref-subst.html):

```
<transcription>
<subst>    
    <del>wrong</del>
    <add>right</add>
</subst>    
</transcription>
```

Now I want to process this recording of a transcription in different ways using XSLT.

If I just want to present the correction to the user, I could use an XSLT template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="subst"><xsl:apply-templates select="./add"/></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subst/add"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
```

However, I could also write:

```
<xsl:template match="subst"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subst/add"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

<!-- del: ignore contents -->
<xsl:template match="subst/del"></xsl:template>
```

In the first case, I explicitly only address `add` inside `<subst>`, ignoring `<del>`.

In the second case, I ignore `<del>` by providing a template that does not do anything with the element, resulting in the same effect.

If I am not mistaken, the two ways are equivalent. Which one is preferable?

Comment: There is no `subst` in your input, so `<xsl:template match="subst">` will not do anything -  and that's where I stopped reading.

Comment: You're not "ignoring del" by not having a template for it. It would hit a default template then.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the subst element. Thx, Stefan, your comment was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, not processing nodes at all is preferable to processing them with an empty template. But sometimes the alternative is more convenient, e.g. for reasons of code readability.

Comment: For the first case (expression for select), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049741/what-does-it-mean-apply-templates-select

Comment: @user130685 What would I be looking for there?

Comment: "select all element children and apply the templates that match them." So the elements that do not match the expression, are not processed at all. What about the comment "It would hit a default template then" in this case?

Comment: I am not talking about the * operator, but about an expression like select="./add". I guess the answer in the cited post refers to the * operator.

Comment: @user130685 if you do not apply templates to a node, then it will not be processed at all. If you do apply templates to it, then it will be processed - either by a matching template, or  (if no matching template exists) by one of the built-in templates. I am afraid I still do not see the relevance of the link.